# margin of buttons in windows phone apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am dynamically generating a matrix of buttons(dynamic gridSize),everything is perfect except that I am unable to get them without spaces between them.I tried but could not understand how to use margin attribute.

460 is the width and height of `gridPanel` over which I am adding buttons

Here is the code from my `app.cs` file

```
private void generateButtons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++)
        {
            buttons[i, j] = new Button();
            buttons[i, j].Content = "0";
            buttons[i, j].FontSize = 16;
            buttons[i, j].Height = 460/gridSize;
            double size = buttons[i, j].Height;
            buttons[i, j].Width = 460/gridSize;
            buttons[i, j].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            opened[i, j] = false;
            buttons[i, j].Margin = new Thickness(0 + (size * j), 0 + (size * i), 464 -                    (0 + (size * (j + 1))), 464 - (0 + (size * (i + 1))));
            buttons[i, j].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(cell_Click);
            this.gridPanel.Children.Add(buttons[i, j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: @HighCore remind me to tell you how much I normally enjoy reading your comments while thinking the same thing...oh wait, guess I just did. ;)

Comment: @ChrisW. It does get kinda repetitive after a while, though.

Comment: @Yandros hah, ya you've got a point there too.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is, can you make it more explicit?

Comment: @mcgarnagle i just want no spacing between buttons which are dynamically generated.there can be any number of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most 'input controls' (buttons, textboxes etc) on Windows Phone have default spacings equal to 6.0 or 12.0. The simple workaround is to adjust margins of button by -12.

Sugestion unrelated to the question - when you want to populate a Grid uniformally with buttons, it would be perhaps easier, to generate a desired number of rows and columns and put every button in the different cell (with button.margin always equal to -12). All sizing calculations would be done by the Grid. Like this (gridPanel is Grid).

```
// generate rows and columns
for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
{
    gridPanel.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    gridPanel.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
}

for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++)
    {
        buttons[i, j] = new Button
            {
                Content = "0",
                FontSize = 16,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
                // all buttons have the same margin, no calculation needed
                Margin = new Thickness(-12) 
            };
        // placing in a row and column via attached properties
        buttons[i, j].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
        buttons[i, j].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
        buttons[i, j].Click += new RoutedEventHandler(cell_Click);
        opened[i, j] = false;
        this.gridPanel.Children.Add(buttons[i, j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do that...i mean which argument of thickness should i alter by -12. Also how to make a dynamic grid and make it to place buttons in its cells automatically?

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal I think that @lisp means to use a uniform thickness, as in `new Thickness(-12)`.